# Turning Off Tooltips using Media Queries

Tags: jquery, html, tooltip, media-queries, qtip

How can I add in media queries so that the qtip does not display when scaled down to mobile sizes? Here is the jquery I am using.

```
jQuery.root.find(".tooltip").qtip({
position:{
corner: {
tooltip: "bottomMiddle",
target: "topMiddle"
}
},
style: {
border: {
width: 2,
radius: 3
},
padding: 7,
width: 350,
tip: true,
name: "light"
}
});
```

Here is the HTML:

### Advanced Track

I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.tooltip {
display: none;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the elements that qtip creates shows that the tool tips themselves are created with class `.qtip`

So

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .qtip {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Should do the trick